# Hipi Average no of pixels program fails due to yarn containers error in cloudera quickstart vm

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm, hipi

I am newbie to HIPI/Hadoop so I choose cloudera quickstart vm (5.4.2). I am following [getting started](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/gettingstarted.html) tutorial to do that. 
While running I find that I have files in hib file as shown below:

```
[cloudera@quickstart tools]$ ./hibInfo.sh examples/sampleNew.hib --show-meta



Input HIB: examples/sampleNew.hib
Display meta data: true
Display EXIF data: false
IMAGE INDEX: 0
   1244 x 829
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/01.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 1
   1106 x 829
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/02.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 2
   933 x 700
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/03.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 3
   1106 x 829
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/04.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 4
   1244 x 829
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/05.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 5
   1555 x 1166
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/06.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 6
   1244 x 829
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/07.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 7
   1244 x 829
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/08.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 8
   576 x 383
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/09.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 9
   576 x 383
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/10.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 10
   737 x 475
   format: 1
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/11.jpg}
IMAGE INDEX: 11
   614 x 460
   format: 2
   meta: {source=/home/cloudera/Downloads/hipi-release/web/examples/testimages/12.png}
Found [12] images.
```

But when I am trying to execute with jar file I am getting the following error:

```
[cloudera@quickstart helloWorld]$ hadoop jar build/libs/helloWorld.jar examples/sampleNew.hib sampleimages_average
15/10/27 03:22:30 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/10/27 03:22:37 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/10/27 03:22:40 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
Spawned 1map tasks
15/10/27 03:22:48 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/10/27 03:22:50 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1445938202522_0003
15/10/27 03:23:00 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1445938202522_0003
15/10/27 03:23:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1445938202522_0003/
15/10/27 03:23:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1445938202522_0003
15/10/27 03:23:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1445938202522_0003 running in uber mode : false
15/10/27 03:23:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/10/27 03:23:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1445938202522_0003 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1445938202522_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1445938202522_0003_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1445938202522_0003/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1445938202522_0003_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

Log File under resource manager says:

```
Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be configured
java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all.
```

Help me. I am not able to find the error.

I am using Java 1.8, Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.2,

HADOOP_CLASSPATH :   /usr/lib/hadoop/lib
HADOOP_YARN_HOME :   /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn
HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME:  /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
HADOOP_CONF_DIR   :  /etc/hadoop/conf

I have tested with wordcount example and that is a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by reverting back my java version which was a mismatch between two HIPI and hadoop. I build hipi with hadoop java version and this issue resolves.

Comment: I am using Java 1.8.0_77 version in my system and 1.8.0_91 in server.  I am getting same container issue when running. Is there any problem arises with build version change?

Comment: Its possible. Please check.